# add to cart route node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i want to add to my cart within a node.js express application but without have to refresh or to redirect in the route. is there a way to do this? this is the route of the "add to cart" function:

```
router.get('/add-to-cart/:id/:pices', function(req, res) {
  var pices = req.params.pices;
  var productId = req.params.id;

  var cart = new Cart(req.session.cart ? req.session.cart : { });

  Product.findById(productId, function (err, product) {
    if (err) {
      return res.redirect('/');
    }
    cart.add(product, product._id, pices);
    req.session.cart = cart;
    res.redirect('/products');
  });
});
```

as you can see I redirect to ('/products') every time I add a product to the cart. is there a way around that so that the page does not refresh every time?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not a issue with the backend but rather on the frontend. I presume you are using a form element with its `action` set to that endpoint.

What you are looking for is [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) with [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). Not quite sure on the design of your frontend but I'll give it a guess:

On the frontend in a script:

- Get `yourForm`
- Add a `submit` event listener
- Prevent the default event (redirecting)
- Send a get request to the endpoint
- Parse it `{credentials: "include"}` so the backend knows whos cart to add to. (it sends session data)

```js
yourForm.addEventListener("submit", async function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    await fetch(ev.target.getAttribute("action"), {credentials: "include"});
});
```

(also for that type of action you may want to use a HTTP post request)

Comment: Frontend: `<% for (var i=0; i < products.length;  i++ ) { %>
   <div class="col-sm-4 <%= products[i]["category"] %>">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="/pictures/product.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title"><%= products[i]["name"] %> <br><%= products[i]["price"] %> RON</h5>
            <input type="number" min="1" max="10" class="numberForTheCart" id="<%= products[i]["_id"] %>" value="1"> <a id="a<%= products[i]["_id"] %>" href="/produse/add-to-cart/<%= products[i]["_id"] %>/1" class="btn btn-light">Add to cart</a>`

Comment: my frontend is rapped in a div. It is a card format as I have many products that are loaded from the database. At the end I have a button with the href to the "add-to-cart" route.

Comment: @FlaviuTamasan In that case `yourForm` would be `yourAnchor` and bound to the anchor tag. Rather than listening for the "submit" event listen for the "click" event. Not sure what you provided as `href` points to `/produse/add-to-cart/` not `/add-to-cart/:id/:pices`. And how does your frontend send the quantity?